# Obtaining broadcast variables successfully ran on standalone, but failed in the cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to broadcast an array in a cluster environment so that it can be used on each executor, but it failed.
example:

```
val broadcast_v1: Broadcast[Array[Int]] = sc.broadcast(Array(7, 8, 9))
val count1 = rdd01.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, iter) => {
                println("the " + idx + " s block ...")
                val value = broadcast_v1.value
                println("get broadcast data ....")
                println(value.mkString("||"))
                println("get over .. ")
                Iterator.empty
            }).count()
```

error log:

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Task not serializable
StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2346)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
  ... 42 elided
```

The problem is how to change this code so that broadcast variables can be successfully used in a cluster environment, the above code can run successfully under standalone environment.

I tried to add a scala class that inherits Serializable, but it still did not broadcast successfully too.

Comment: Usually there is something more specific in the stack trace showing which field is not serializable.  It'd be good if you can show that.